# Running python script with parameters in Pycharm and Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-requests, pycharm

I try to send an authorizing request to some API via python `requests`. 
The code looks like

```
import requests
import argparse
import json

URL = "some url"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("username", help="Username")
parser.add_argument("password", help="Password")
args = parser.parse_args()


def get_token(username, password):
    url = URL + "/auth"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    params = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }
    r = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))['data']['token']

token = get_token(args.username, args.password)
print(token)
```

Password contains different symbols including .$)? etc.

When I am passing args via Pycharm Run/Debug Configurations Parameters with quotes (e.g. `"abcde" "abcde"`) all is ok.

But when I try to run script from Terminal (Pycharm or Ubuntu terminal) via `python -m scriptname "abcde" "abcde"`, I receive next message in response: `{"message":"invalid login data","statusCode":400,"status":"BAD_REQUEST"}`

I suppose there is some problem with string encoding, but can't find it.

File encoding (shown in the right down corner of the window in Pycharm) is UTF-8. String encoding in terminal `echo $LANG` is en_US.UTF-8. `python -c "import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)"` also returns UTF-8.

---

**UPDATE**

I've just noticed that a certain part of the password is disappearing while I pass it as a param in the terminal. 
I have a password with `$qTyqf` text inside (e.g. `abcde$qTyqf§abcde`), and this part is just removed while running from the terminal. Why and how to avoid this?

Comment: in the command line/terminal what do you get if you run python -V ? is this is the same python version as you are using within pycharm?

Comment: I activated virtual environment before executing script in Terminal, so version must be the same. Python version is 3.6.7

Comment: Instead of python requests, you could use sysargs (https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/argv/more-fun-with-sys-argv ), it might be easier to use

Comment: Does the error appear when you try to receive the arguments (line 7-11) or when you execute request.post in line 20?

Comment: I suppose you meant using sysargs instead of argsparse. I've tried but it doesn't help. 
I also tried to add `print (params)` in `get_token`, args are present in dict and look like normal, but I still get  `invalid login data` in message while running from terminal

Comment: with sysargs you dont need to supply any quotes. Have you tried it without? python might think the quotes are part of your username&password

Comment: I get the next error while running with params without quotes from terminal 
```bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've found an answer.

I used double quotas (") for passing arguments, and part of the password argument started with `$abc` was replaced with (I suppose) empty value of the env variable `abc`. So part of the password was just disappeared and I couldn't login with the wrong password.

Solution. I replaced double quotas (") with single quotas (') and now all is ok.

Comment: If you `$ export X=y`, then bash will interpret `ls "$X"` as `ls y`, and will interpret `ls '$X'` as looking for a two-character filename. You were getting hung up on the shell variable interpolation that happened before python even started running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need quotes for passing arguments to command line?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.argv)" x$ y
```

works as expected and I receive "x$", "y" as arguments

Comment: I need quotas because password contains symbols like ). If I don't use quotas, I receive the next error ```bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'```

Answer (score 0):

Using sys.arg from python might be a lot easier and won't manipulate your input in any way.

cmd>myfile.py username password

- sys.argv[0] is the filename
- sys.argv[1] would be your username
- sys.argv[2] would be your password

Usage:

```
import requests
import argparse
import json
import sys

URL = "some url"
arguments = sys.argv[1:]
print("Argument Test: " + str(arguments))

def get_token(username, password):
    url = URL + "/auth"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    params = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }
    r = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=headers)
    return json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))['data']['token']

token = get_token(arguments[0] , arguments[1])
print(token)
```

Comment: Thank for the code, but as I wrote in comment, I still get error while trying to run script from the terminal. No problems while running from pycharm with both sys args and argsparse.

Comment: Updated the question